# How to catch bad web3 eth node endpoint

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-hdwallet-provider

In the project I am working on (next.js + react) users will enter their own Infura endpoint to connect on-chain. Now is there a way to validate the endpoint they supplied (in this case their input is saved in their browser session storage). When I purposefully enter a bad `Infura project id` it doesn't get caught in the `try/catch`but I get a `unhandled runtime error` later on. I would like to handle these error somehow, where can I catch them?

```js
//web3.js file
const Web3 = require('web3')
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider')

let web3

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  try {
    const walletProvider = new HDWalletProvider(
      sessionStorage.getItem('mnemonic'),
      sessionStorage.getItem('http')
    )
    web3 = new Web3(walletProvider)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    web3 = null
  }
  module.exports = {
    web3: web3,
  }
}
```

1st error

```json
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: Unknown Error: invalid project id
```

2nd error

```json
Error: Unknown Error: invalid project id

{
  "originalError": {}
}
```

3rd error

```json
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: Unknown Error: invalid project id
```

Comment: Did you try making a call to web3 immediately? For example `getBlock("latest")`.

Comment: @Ismael tried a `web3.eth.getBlockNumber()` right after web3 initialization but page still crashes, If i make it an async function and put `await` before the `getBlockNumber` it does enter the catch statment but page also crashes

Comment: That looks like a bug with web3 or HDWalletProvider. The other options will be to make a JSON-RPC query to provided URL, see the format expected https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_blocknumber.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for pointing me in this direction!  I ended up using axios to make a post request to the supplied endpoint, sending a JSON-RPC request calling the `eth_blockNumber` and use that as validation that the supplied infura enpoint is working! Feel free to make an answer and I can accept it! :)